# Windows won't maximize on multiple monitor setup

Tags: display, dock, window-manager

I have two external monitors connected to my macbook and the dock is on the very leftmost monitor.  The non-dock monitor seems to think it has the dock because it will not allow me to expand windows into the area where the dock would be.

Additionally the monitor **with** the dock will expand windows fully right behind the dock.

I have tried moving the dock to this monitor and then away from it and disconnecting and reconnecting the monitor altogether but I have not restarted yet as I would prefer to solve this problem without a reboot if possible.  Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

[image]

I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.3 on a 2016 macbook pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by killing the Dock process (it will restart on its own):

```
sudo killall Dock
```